# How to solve the exact change problem using sets in python?

Tags: python, set

Set: Do you have the exact change? You are given an infinite supply of bills of three denominations (say, 10 $, 20 $, and 50 $ bills). Given a price, can you identify if you have exact change summing up to that price? For instance, using these three types of bills, we can pay 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 $, etc., but we cannot pay 55, in that case print “Not Possible”. It is also possible that the same price can be constructed using multiple combinations of bills. For instance, 50 $ can be constructed using three bills of 10 and one bill of 20, or by directly using a single 50 $ bill. We can print all the possible combinations. Consider the following sample inputs and outputs.
Sample input: 50
Output
320
120
005

```
amt=int(input())
if amt%10!=0:
    print('Not possible')
else:
    n_10=amt/10
    n_20=amt/20
    n_50=amt/50
    st=set()
    if(n_10*10+n_20*20+n_50*50==3*amt):
        st1={n_10,n_20,n_50}
        print(st1)
```

Comment: You don't need to test all possibilities. If the price is a multiple of 10 this is always possible with bills of 10/20/50

Comment: I do need to print out all the possibilities, how do I obtain those?

Comment: If you always have 10/20/50, you can always find the minimal combination of bills by getting the largest bills first then then smaller ones. E.g. 80 = 50 + 20 + 10. Then you can compute the combinations from the combinations of the individual bills. 20 = 10 + 10, 50 = 20 + 20 + 10 or 20 + 10 + 10 + 10 or 5 * 10. You can either use recursion of iteration.

Comment: Also see [coin problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Comment: You can also use recursion directly. Check which bills you can add to the existing set, then repeat until you reach the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something very basic to begin with. Note that it generates duplicates (10+20+50 and also 20+50+10, etc.).

```
def pay(paid, outstanding, bills):
    if outstanding == 0:
        print(paid)
    elif outstanding > 0:
        for b in bills:
            pay(paid + [b], outstanding - b, bills)

BILLS = (10, 20, 50)
pay([], 80, BILLS)
```

---

step 2: we don't want to print the bills combinations, we want to process the data, let's convert the main function to a generator and hide the `paid` list as an unimportant implementation detail:

```
def _pay(paid, outstanding, bills):
    if outstanding == 0:
        yield paid
    elif outstanding > 0:
        for b in bills:
            yield from _pay(paid + [b], outstanding - b, bills)

def pay(outstanding, bills):
    return list(_pay([], outstanding, bills))

BILLS = (10, 20, 50)
print(pay(80, BILLS))
```

---

step 3: Not we finally count the bills with `Counter` and remove duplicates with `set`. (It can be further improved)

```
from collections import Counter

def _pay(paid, outstanding, bills):
    if outstanding == 0:
        yield Counter(paid)
    elif outstanding > 0:
        for b in bills:
            yield from _pay(paid + [b], outstanding - b, bills)

def pay(outstanding, bills):
    return set(
        tuple(cnt[b] for b in BILLS)
        for cnt in _pay([], outstanding, bills)
        )   

BILLS = (10, 20, 50) 
print(pay(80, BILLS))
```